# Can I make a module called 'modules' inside CI HMVC modules folder?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

Im developing a module with CodeIgniter WirezDesign HMVC to install modules with a .zip file. Do anyone know if I can create a module called `modules`inside HMVC folder which is called `modules` too? Or will be some problems?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html)?  Did you try it?

Comment: @Sparky Yeah, I read it but I think is more about  [this documentation](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc) than codeigniter doc. But unfortunately, I didn't find nothing about this.

Comment: Did you try it??  Either it will work or it won't.